# Cash register form

Tags: c#, beginner, wpf, xaml

I'm pretty darn new to C# and to be honest in programming.

I'm experimenting on making a cash register type program and I picked WPF because its been recommended as better than Forms when it comes to resizing and graphics stuff.

I'm looking for feedback on how I could better my XAML.

```
    <Page x:Class="Registry_Project.RightPanel_Menu"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Registry_Project"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="RightPanel_Menu" MinHeight="720" MinWidth="340">

<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="320*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="LBoxOrder" Margin="10"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Margin="10,0,10,0" Width="70" Background="#FFF13C3C">
            <TextBlock Text="Remove Item" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="18"/>
        </Button>
        <Grid Margin="5" ShowGridLines="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Total:" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Cash:" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Change:" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20"/>

            <TextBlock Text="9999" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="CashBlock" Text="9999" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Text="9999" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="20"/>

        </Grid>
        <Button Content="PAY" Margin="10,0,10,0" FontSize="30" Background="#FF49DA29" Width="70"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="1" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="2" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="3" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="4" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="5" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="6" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="7" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="8" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="9" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="0" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="." FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NumEvent"/>
        <Button Content="Clear" FontSize="18" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2" Width="50" Height="50" Click="clik_Clear"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/257643/2) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: IMHO the best way is to avoid complicated Grids, they tend to be unwieldy. Look at the other ways to construct a UI, e.g. StackPanels etc. Unfortunately you are new to programming, otherwise I'd advise you to use the MVVM pattern when doing WPF. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thank you for the feedback... ill be sure to look into it as part of my learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **Suggested Actions**

There is a new feature called **Suggested Actions** that enables easy access to common properties when a control is selected. This feature is available in  [Visual Studio 2019 Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) version 16.6 and later. To use it, first enable it through **Options > Preview Features > XAML Suggested Actions**.Once enabled, click on a supported control and use the “light bulb” to expand and interact with the Suggested Actions UI.

[image]

More information about this feature can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improvements-to-xaml-tooling-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-7-preview-1/).